# How can I divide ajax post?

Tags: ajax, post, request, httpresponse

I have a very simple Ajax post file uploader.

My problem is: I don't want to send about 50 request at the same time.

```
//$scope.up.length - number of files .. number of requests
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.up.length; i++) {

var file = $scope.up[$scope.i];
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

$.ajax({
url : url,
type : "post",
data : formData,
processData : false,
contentType : false,
async : true,
success : function() {
alert(done);
},
 error : function() {
 alert("error");
 }
});
}
```

I want to divide the number of request. For example if the max number of request is 5. If we got first 5 respons from server the post send the next 5 request until we have.

Comment: Hi @user3224068, nice first post. You can easily mark source-code with help of having 4 spaces before every line. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help.